# Groupby and highest value of a column rowwise

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

The following table has three columns Date Item and price column. I have copied gs table here.

Date            Item    Price
01-01-2023  Copper  2
01-02-2023  Copper  3
01-03-2023  Copper  3.5
01-04-2023  Copper  4
01-05-2023  Copper  3.5
01-06-2023  Copper  3.2
01-07-2023  Copper  3.75
01-08-2023  Copper  4.25
01-09-2023  Copper  4.5
01-01-2023  Steel   100
01-02-2023  Steel   99
01-03-2023  Steel   101
01-04-2023  Steel   100.95
01-05-2023  Steel   101.5
01-06-2023  Steel   102
01-07-2023  Steel   101.5
01-08-2023  Steel   103
01-09-2023  Steel   103.5

I want fourth column so that it has highest price day by day using groupby.

Date            Item    Price   Highest Price
01-01-2023  Copper  2
01-02-2023  Copper  3   3
01-03-2023  Copper  3.5 3.5
01-04-2023  Copper  4   4
01-05-2023  Copper  3.5 4
01-06-2023  Copper  3.2 4
01-07-2023  Copper  3.75    4
01-08-2023  Copper  4.25    4.25
01-09-2023  Copper  4.5 4.5
01-01-2023  Steel   100
01-02-2023  Steel   99  100
01-03-2023  Steel   101 101
01-04-2023  Steel   100.95  101
01-05-2023  Steel   101.5   101.5
01-06-2023  Steel   102 102
01-07-2023  Steel   101.5   102
01-08-2023  Steel   103 103
01-09-2023  Steel   103.5   103.5

I tried groupby and max for each row and then comparing each row of new column